# how to use reactivePoll in r shiny to check for presence of a file after selecting the parent directory where the file resides

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to start a `reactivePoll` only after selecting a parent directory using `shinyFiles`. I want the function to check based on the selection. I keep getting `checkFunc` errors about `argument is of length 0`. I looked this up and typically happens when the vector is `logical(0)`. I got this example from [reactivePoll example](https://harveyl888.github.io/blog/shiny-background-process/). Please provide some help, thanks.

```
  Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero             
  reactivePoll
  observeEventHandler
  shiny::runApp
```

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

home_dir <- "/top/directory"
server <- function(input, output, session) {
pdf_file <- 'full_report.pdf'

  status <- reactiveValues(text = 'Idle')
    
  shinyDirChoose(
                 input,
                 "dir",
                 roots = c(home = home_dir)
                 )
  dir <- reactive(
      basename(parseDirPath(c(home=home_dir), input$dir))
      )

  output$dirpath_dply <- renderText({
      dir()
  })


  observeEvent(input$dir, {
    session$sendCustomMessage('disableButton', 'dir')
    status$text <- 'Running...'

    # mimic httr post 
    Sys.sleep(5) 

    message(dir())
    req(dir()) # seems to prevent error but just hangs?

    omiqPDF_file <- reactivePoll(2000, session,
                  checkFunc = function() {
                    if (file.exists(file.path(home_dir, dir(), pdf_file)))
                      file.info(file.path(home_dir, dir(), pdf_file))$mtime
                    else 
                        ''
                    },
                  valueFunc = function() {
                    if ( length(list.files(path = paste0(home_dir, '/', input$dir), 
                                           pattern = pdf_file,
                                           recursive=TRUE) ) > 0 )
                        file.info(file.path(home_dir, dir(), pdf_file))$size > 5000
                    else
                      ''
                }
      )

      observe({
        if (omiqPDF_file() == TRUE) {
          session$sendCustomMessage('enableButton', 'dir')
          status$text <- paste0('Completed for ', dir())
        } 
      })

  })
  
  output$uiStatus <- renderUI(
    h4(paste0('STATUS: ', status$text), style="color:red;")
  )
  
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  singleton(tags$head(HTML('
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Enable button
        Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("enableButton", function(id) {
      $("#" + id).removeAttr("disabled");
      });
      // Disable button
        Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("disableButton", function(id) {
      $("#" + id).attr("disabled", "true");
      });
    })
    </script>
    ')
  )),
  navbarPage(
    "main",
    tabPanel("navbar 1",
        sidebarPanel(
          tags$h2("HEADER"),
          shinyDirButton("dir", "Input Directory", ""),
          br()
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h1("HEADER MAIN"),
      h4("DIRPATH OUTPUT"),
      verbatimTextOutput("dirpath_dply"),
      uiOutput('uiStatus')
    )
  ),
   tabPanel("navbar 2", "blank"),
   tabPanel("navbar 3", "blank")
)
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I don't know if `if(omiqPDF_file() == TRUE)` is what you want, I don't know if that reactive generates a boolean value. Have you tried `if(grepl('COMPLETED', omiqPDF_file()))`?

Comment: i don't have a logfile that would contain 'COMPLETED' in my example. I would have a .pdf file and i just want to check the presence of it.

Comment: Can you explain what the expected output of `omiqPDF_file()` is

Comment: yeah, if the length of list.files() output is > 0 which means the .pdf file exists in the selected directory

Comment: I see that you define checkFunc and valueFunc, but you never actually call them within your reactive. Have you tried including function calls: `checkFunc()` and `valueFunc()`?

Comment: i don think you really need to do that if i understand `reactivePoll` correctly. i think i found out the problem. within `valueFunc` need to use `dir()` not `input$dir`. it works but only for one time, subsequent clicks on the `shinyDirChoose` gives me `Uncaught TypeError: this.$socket is null` within the browser console. so only way is to refresh each time. not sure what to do with that